# Laravel 5.1 Routes that have question mark

Tags: php, laravel, routes, laravel-5.1, laravel-routing

I'm trying to create a route in Laravel 5.1 that will search the records base on "keyword". I like to include a `?` in my url for more readability. The problem is that when I'm including the `?` and test the route with postman it returns nothing. But when I remove the `?` and replaced it with `/` and test it with postman again it will return the value of keyword. Does Laravel route supports `?`?

```
//Routes.php
Route::get('/search?keyword={keyword}', [
    'as' => 'getAllSearchPublications', 
    'uses' => 'PublicationController@index'
]);

//Publication Controller
public function index($keyword)
{
    return $keyword;
}
```

I've been searching the internet for hours now and I've read the Laravel documentation, But I can't find the answer. Thank you.

Comment: I need to satisfy communicating with a legacy API calls that send a parameter.

E.g. /customer/?id=1

Can't figure out how to do it.

Did you ever get it working?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I believe you are talking about query strings. To accept query parameters, you don't pass it as an argument. So, for example, your route should look more plain like this:

```
Route::get('/search', [
    'as' => 'getAllSearchPublications', 
    'uses' => 'PublicationController@index'
]);
```

Note: I dropped `?keyword={keyword}`.

Then, in your controller method, you can grab the query parameter by calling the `query` method on your `Request` object.

```
public function index(Request $request)
{
    return $request->query('keyword');
}
```

If you didn't already, you will need to import `use Illuminate\Http\Request;` to use the `Request` class.

Comment: So what is this "as"? What purpose does it serve? And what is this "getAllSearchPublication"? And what is this "keywords"? I have a domain.com/something/?myquerystring And I need to get that myquerystring. That is the oembed convention to use domain/oembed/?something with the questionmark

Answer (score 0):

Use

`$resquest`

Parameter in your controller action to get the query parameter. Instead of using `"?"` to create in your route.

Comment: Thank you for your response. Thomas Kim answer is more detailed though.